# Input unicode to vim

Tags: vim, gvim, unicode

Firstly, I am happy with vim due to its godlike key combination. But sometimes, I really want to write with my language in unicode, I find a solution in vim help file which is using disgraphs: `<C-K><char1><char2>` . But it is not the way I type unicode, **is there any way that I can input unicode to vim using app like ibus [ I windows I use unikey, you guys won't know about it]**

Comment: IBus works in vim just fine here...

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: @romainl: My language is Vietnamese. 
@Ignacio: Are you sure ? It doesn't show a thing when I use ibus, do I need some any configuration ?

Comment: Yes. http://i.imgur.com/4VuuE.png

Comment: @Ignacio: Can you post your vimrc here ?

Comment: It's just the stock Fedora vimrc, which would be too large to include in its entirety.

Comment: you can paste your vimrc on http://ideone.com/. thanks first :)

Comment: It would probably be easier on everyone involved to just grab the `vim-minimal` and `vim-enhanced` packages and use `rpm2cpio` and `cpio` to extract the contents.

Comment: I use gvim on windows, but anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for a long time no answer and comment. It looks like that the problem from my input tool which is unikey. Thanks all for the helps.